# Hide Committed Data

Tags: oracle-adf

I facing an issues no to show committed data in my table. For example once user upload data from excel it will display under the table below. Once user click save those data will be committed to database and it won't show again. Any suggestion for resolving this issues?(i am using adf Studio Edition Version 11.1.1.7.0) Thank you very much.

Comment: We need more info in order to come up with an answer. For example, you are mentioning uploading data from excel. Such feature doesn't exist in ADF (unless you are using ADF Desktop Integration maybe? ), so how do you do this exactly? We would need more technical context.

Comment: Hi;i use managed Bean to extract the data inside the excel and insert it inside the table. I didn't use any Desktop Integration.

Answer (score 0):

What's the data-model that populates your table? Once you click the commit button you'll need to remove the rows from that data model. So for example if your data model is based on a query - then you will need to find a SQL that doesn't include the rows that are in the table.

Comment: Hi, at the end i did it by create 1 field call save status and use it as indicate whether my data is uplaoded or not. And in my taskflow i default create insert as default.